# Ignite Woo Wishlist

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an issue with a WooCommerce Plugin called Wishlists pro. Everything is working fine for all my wishlists in the ecommerce store except one of them - when I go to the wishlist in the WordPress Admin, the wishlist is cut-off halfway down the screen.

This cant be a setup issue as on-site, the wishlist still has all the products listed just fine and users can purchase them - it's only in the WP admin that t

The broken wishlist, it stops halfway through the products in the wishlist: !https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0kCh.jpg

Another wishlist (note how after  products, the rest of the options show): !https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcjCl.jpg

Do you think this could be a database issue? And if so, why would the products still show on-site in within the relevant wishlist?

Let me know if you need any further information.

Thanks,

B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - the database was corrupt and WordPress stopped rendering the page at that line